# Will this circuit function as an automatic supply changeover upon main supply failure?

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell

I have drawn up this circuit as a supply system for an automatic changeover from the mains supply to the solar cell - battery supply.

[image: Changeover Circuit]

Will the circuit function as intended? What is the correct way to draft this?

Comment: Have you traced out from both terminals of the battery?

Comment: Is that solar cell meant to charge the battery? Because where it is - it won't...

Comment: I find it highly unlikely your circuit does what you want it to do; solar cells with no control / conversion electronics in series to a battery plainly makes no sense at all, unless you want a sun-brightness-controlled kind-of-similar-to-a-controlled-voltage-source thing. So, I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: What are these relays intended for? You don't need them, you may simply parallel the battery and the rectifier output, use an "ideal diode" chip to in series to the solar cell and parallel that series to the rectifier, too. The diodes on the right and the smoothing cap are useless, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Pp9T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can buy the "ideal diode" as a ready-made chip or create a small circuit yourself. It's basically a MOSFET which, unlike a PN diode, has a very small forward voltage drop. You may also use a normal PN or Schottky diode if you can live with the ~0.7V drop (likely for a 24V system).

The rectifier itself has two diodes going to battery plus, so no further diodes needed. The battery does the smoothing, so no smoothing cap needed.

EDIT: Charge controller added.
EDIT: Mains fuse added.

Comment: DO you really want to encourage people to attach a battery directly to a supply like that??????

Comment: For a lead battery – typical solar backup battery –, this doubtlessly works.

Comment: Clearly you have never seen a SLA battery explode on charge.

Comment: I've seen lead acid batteries explode : far from funny , best place to be when it happens is somewhere else...

Comment: "Will it work" is one question - "is it safe" and "is it good practise"  are better questions...

Comment: Ok, have added a charge controller.

Comment: Circuit breakers / fuse then +1 from me...

Comment: We get further away from a sketch… it was intended as a sketch…

Comment: Much better :).

Comment: Go on have one for the battery as well :) ... ! and i voted

Comment: This should be inside the charge controller, shouldn't it?